# Posting a comment on a blog post loads another blog post and comment is linked to the new blog post

Tags: comments, blog

Each time a new comment is added to a blog post, another blog post is loaded, and the comment added is linked to the blog post loaded.

Comment: You need to provide WAY more information...  don't even know where to begin helping you with this. Is this a custom theme you built, when did the behaviour start, are you using any plugins, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.